# CSCore Application Audio Mixer Name+Peak

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, audio, cscore

i try to get the peak(the level of the green bar in the audio mixer of win7) of a processID for example 5640 - Spotify.

Searched at the Internet for a good library. I found CSCore.

Now I have this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var sessionManager = GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow.Render))
        {
            using (var sessionEnumerator = sessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator())
            {
                foreach (var session in sessionEnumerator)
                {
                    using (var audioMeterInformation = session.QueryInterface<AudioMeterInformation>())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(audioMeterInformation.GetPeakValue()*100);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static AudioSessionManager2 GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow dataFlow)
    {
        using (var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator())
        {
            using (var device = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(dataFlow, Role.Multimedia))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("DefaultDevice: " + device.FriendlyName);
                var sessionManager = AudioSessionManager2.FromMMDevice(device);
                return sessionManager;
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

The Documentation of http://cscore.codeplex.com/ doesn't helped me. Can someone give me an example with my code, how i can get an output like this:

58,31232---Process-ID---Spotify

At the Moment it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: That was an example of a peak. If i listen to music the peak changes constantly. If you execute it it shows values(Peaks) that are standing for the audio applications who are running. But I can not assign it. I need a name AND the peak in my output.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your code to something like this (also take a look at the unit-tests of cscore):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var sessionManager = GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow.Render))
        using (var sessionEnumerator = sessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator())
        {
            foreach (var session in sessionEnumerator)
            {
                Assert.IsNotNull(session);

                using (var session2 = session.QueryInterface<AudioSessionControl2>())
                using (var audioMeterInformation = session.QueryInterface<AudioMeterInformation>())
                {   
                    Debug.WriteLine("Process: {0}; Peak: {1:P}", 
                        session2.Process == null ? String.Empty : session2.Process.MainWindowTitle,
                        audioMeterInformation.GetPeakValue()*100);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static AudioSessionManager2 GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow dataFlow)
    {
        using (var enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator())
        {
            using (var device = enumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(dataFlow, Role.Multimedia))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("DefaultDevice: " + device.FriendlyName);
                var sessionManager = AudioSessionManager2.FromMMDevice(device);
                return sessionManager;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, thanks! But sessionEnumerator isnt known in your Code. And if i add it Assert.IsNotNull cant access beacause of the security level. Can you correct your code pls?

Comment: I've changed my code... but if you take a look at your question, you can see that you've already done all necessary. I just forgot to copy one single line of your code: `using (var sessionEnumerator = sessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator())`

Comment: I tried your code. But "Assert.IsNotNull(session);" is not available in the current context.

Comment: Put your Code into VisualStudio and see it.

Comment: You don't need that. It is just copied from the unittests... remove it. That's all.