# Foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type "?"

Tags: c#, naudio

I have the following piece of code:

```
using (var sessionManager = GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow.Render))
{
    using (var sessionEnumerator = sessionManager.GetSessionEnumerator())
    {
        foreach (var session in sessionEnumerator)
        {
         //Code
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error saying

> Foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type "?"

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What does `GetSessionEnumerator()` return? I think it is not an `IEnumerable` while `foreach` expects an IEnumerable

Comment: Try changing the "var sessionEnumerator" to the Actual type returned by "GetSessionEnumerator" and see what the compiler says.

Comment: The odd thing is, that line of code is 'correct' in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999531/cscore-application-audio-mixer-namepeak#24015857), this [unit test](https://github.com/filoe/cscore/blob/master/CSCore.Test/CoreAudioAPI/AudioSessionTests.cs#L127), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297577/get-processname-or-id-from-cscore-audiostream)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the name implies `sessionEnumerator` is an IEnumerator but foreach requires IEnumerable. here is the alternative of foreach statement.

```
using (var sessionManager = GetDefaultAudioSessionManager2(DataFlow.Render))
{
    while(sessionEnumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var session = sessionEnumerator.Current;

        // Code
    }
}
```